# reactjs svg image rendered with zero width and height in IE

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, svg

I created a ReactJS component to display edit/delete buttons in each row of a data table.

This is my component:

```
import React from 'react';

const iconStyle = {
    border:'none',
    boxShadow:'none',
    backgroundColor:'transparent',
    cursor:'pointer'

};


const RowEditButtons = (props) => {
    const editButton = props.onEdit ?
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" onClick={props.onEdit.bind(null,props.index)} style={iconStyle}>
            <img src="img/icon-pencil.svg" />
        </button>
            : null;
    const deleteButton = props.onDelete ? 
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" onClick={props.onDelete.bind(null,props.index)} style={iconStyle}>
            <img src="img/close-o.svg" />
        </button>
            : null;

    return (
        <div className="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Edit buttons" >
            {editButton}
            {deleteButton}
        </div>
    );

};

RowEditButtons.propTypes = {
    index: React.PropTypes.number,
    onEdit: React.PropTypes.func,
    onDelete: React.PropTypes.func
};

export default RowEditButtons;
```

I am testing on IE (because that's the company standard) and i have noticed that sometimes the buttons show up and sometimes they don't.  Sometimes they will show on some rows and not others.  It's not consistent.  After looking at the rendered DOM using dev tools, i see that the buttons and images are there, only the images have width="0" and height="0".  I'm not sure what is going on here, if it's the browser, reactjs, or bootstrap.

Does anybody have a clue?

Answer (score 0):

I just added in-line styles to the img element setting width and height to auto.  This seems to have solved the problem.

```
<img style={{width:'auto',height:'auto'}} src="img/icon-pencil.svg" />
```